# What does this cycle do?What is the point?

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-image

```
int myDrawOrder = sprite->GetDrawOrder();
auto iter = mSprites.begin();
for(;iter != mSprites.end(); ++iter)
{
    if(myDrawOrder < (*iter)->GetDrawOrder()) //what does this line mean?
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

`GetDrawOrder()` returns the position of the sprite in the queue.

Comment: That line checks if `myDrawOrder` is smaller than `(*iter)->GetDrawOrder()`.

Comment: It looks like the loop finds a spot in a list, presumably ordered by `GetDrawOrder`, where `sprite` could be inserted while maintaining that order.

Comment: This sets `iter` to the first sprite that has draw order greater than `myDrawOrder`, or to `mSprites.end()` if there's no such sprite. Look at how `iter` is used after the loop.

Comment: Three answers in comments ‍♂️

Comment: Yeah, i get it.Th

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loop iterates over the sprites, and `breaks` when it finds a spite that should be drawn before the `sprite`. You didn't share the rest of the code, but presumably something is then done with that sprite (e.g., it's drawn).

Answer (score 1):

Since `iter` is not local to the loop, it's left *after* the loop pointing to the first element for which `myDrawOrder < (*iter)->GetDrawOrder()` is true (or `mySprites.end()` if there wasn't one).

It's a search operation.

It could also be written thusly:

```
const int myDrawOrder = sprite->GetDrawOrder();
auto iter = std::find_if(
   std::begin(mSprites),
   std::end(mSprites),
   [&](const auto& sprite) {
      return sprite.GetDrawOrder() >= myDrawOrder;
   }
);
```